# ubuntu on power5 ibm p5 9110 510

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on my ibm p5 9110 510 but from manuals i found that  only aix,suse linux,and redhat linux can be installed on that machine.
can any one provide help how to install ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

IBM support for Ubuntu actually started with IBM Power8 and officially is only support on power8 and future power systems. The support actually required changes to the fsp. The older Power system however will support Redhat and SUSE.

See the links below

IBM
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/liaamdistros.htm?lang=en
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/liaamdistrospower7.htm?lang=en

Ubuntu

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/models/?vendors=IBM